# UIPopoverController's contentViewController.viewDidUnload not getting called

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, viewdidunload

When I use a `UIPopoverController` and give it a contentViewController, I cannot seem to get the contentViewController to correctly be deallocated (as evidenced by the fact that the contentViewController.viewDidUnload is never getting called).

**Code to create and display the popup:**

```
PopupTestViewController *popupTest = [[PopupTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopupTestViewController" bundle:nil];
popupTest.mainViewController = self;
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popupTest];
self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = popupTest.view.frame.size;
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:button.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Now I am assuming that the `contentViewController` (in the code above, this is `PopoverTestViewController`) *should* be deallocated when the `UIPopoverController` is closed (whether by clicking off of it, or be explicitly dismissing it).  But `viewDidUnload` is never called.  I did notice, however, that if I define a dealloc method for `PopoverTestViewController`, that is called appropriately.

So my question is: why is `viewDidUnload` never getting called?
(And I'm using ARC).

Comment: How are you defining the `popoverController` `@property`?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to get called. It only gets called when the application receives a memory warning and the receiving `ViewController` has `view` loaded but is off screen.
When the `view` is loaded and retain count reaches zero, `viewDidUnload` is not called.

You can find more details in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2).
Instructions on when to release what objects can be found in the same [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW10).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different than I've used `UIPopoverController`. Since you manually `alloc`'ed `popupTest`, you definitely need to manually `release` it. The `UIPopoverController` instance will retain `popupTest` when `initWithContentViewController:` is called.

Furthermore, if you are defining the `popoverController` property with `retain`, then you're getting a double-retain when you use the `self.popoverController` setter by assigning directly from the `alloc`. The general pattern for setting a `@property` is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Foo* foo;

...

Foo* aFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];
self.foo = aFoo;
[aFoo release];
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using ARC, so there is no need to explicitly release anything.